# Seemingly inappropriate compilation warning with C++/CLI

Tags: c++-cli, command-line-interface

I'm playing with a C++/CLI application that talks to my Isis2 (C# .NET) library.  In the code below I get the error "Warning 3 C4538: 'cli::array ^' : const/volatile qualifiers on this type are not supported".  I highlighted the line that throws this.  I'm baffled: this doesn't have an array, nor does it use const or volatile!  Any suggestions?

```
// CPlusPlus.cpp : main project file.

#include "stdafx.h"
#using <IsisLib.dll>
using namespace Isis;
using namespace System;

void GotNewView(View^ v)
{
   Console::WriteLine("Got a new view: " + v->ToString());
}

public delegate void GotAnInt_T (int i);
void GotAnInt(int i)
{
   Console::WriteLine("Got an int: {0}", i);
}

public delegate void GotTwo_T (String ^s, double d);
void GotTwo(String^ s, double d)
{
   Console::WriteLine("Got a string: <{0}> and a double: {1}", s, d);
}

public delegate void SendsReply_T(int i);
void SendsReply(int i)
{
   thisGroup()->Reply(-i);
}

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{ 
   IsisSystem::Start();
   Group ^g = gcnew Group("test");       <============= THIS LINE
   g->RegisterViewHandler(gcnew ViewHandler(GotNewView));
   g->Handlers[0] += gcnew GotAnInt_T(GotAnInt);
   g->Handlers[0] += gcnew GotTwo_T(GotTwo);
   g->Handlers[1] += gcnew SendsReply_T(SendsReply);
   g->Join();
   g->Send((int^)0, 12345);
   g->Send((int^)0, "Aardvarks are animals", 78.91);
   Console::WriteLine("After Send, testing Query");
   Collections::Generic::List<int>^ results = gcnew Collections::Generic::List<int>();
   int nr = g->Query(Group::ALL, 1, 6543, gcnew EOLMarker(), results);
   IsisSystem::WaitForever();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does your `Group` type have any array type members that are volatile?

Comment: Yes, in the C# code I have a boolean vector declared volatile.  So there is a field foo such that g->foo would be volatile.  BUT if I get rid of the assignment and just do gcnew Group("Foo") the error goes away.  So I was assuming the issue has to do with the assignment...  Am I wrong?

Comment: Unfair!  I post a question about what turns out to be a compiler bug, and someone dings the question as "poorly researched"?  Here's my question to the person who did that: how, may I ask, would you have researched this?  And I did post code that would let you reproduce the issue, if you wanted to.  To me that's way better than a code fragment out of context, especially since this turned out to be correct code that triggers an incorrect warning message!

Comment: I can't answer your question, since I wasn't the person who downvoted, but it seems to me that there are some people who downvote questions that they do not understand (I know that there are a couple of moderators that have a tendency to close questions about topics they don't understand, and I've complained loudly about this on several occasions).  In short, there is little (if any) correlation between the quality of a post and the number of votes it has. In any case, +1, because it's a good question and I don't know of any other online resource that mentions this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known compiler bug:  it is warning about a volatile array member of `Group`.  It shouldn't do that.

The recommended workaround is to disable the warning:

```
#pragma warning (disable: 4538)
```

It may be possible to disable the warning only for the problematic lines of code, though I am not 100% sure, since there's nothing in the C++/CLI code that causes this problem.  You can try:

```
#pragma warning (push)
#pragma warning (disable: 4538)
Group^ g = gcnew Group("test");
#pragma warning (pop)
```

Comment: This pragma does the trick, however would you mind referencing your source that this is a 'compiler bug' ?

Comment: @ajhuddy I am the source (I work on the Visual C++ team at Microsoft).  The compiler incorrectly issues warnings about private members imported from metadata. I don't know whether it has been fixed (am not in the office at this time to verify).