# c++ cli ConcurrentDictionary warning 4538

Tags: c++-cli, warnings, concurrentdictionary

When I have this c++ cli code:

```
#pragma managed
ref class mcSessions: ConcurrentDictionary <String ^, mcSession^> 
{  //<---- warning here
private:
   static mcSessions ^g_Sessions;
       TimeSpan MaxIdleTime;
   mcSessions (TimeSpan newMaxIdleTime);
public:
    static void Initialize (long MaxIdleMinutes);
        static void Shutdown ();
        static void CreateSession (String ^&SessionId);
        static void RunInSession (String ^SessionId, String ^Command);
        static void RemoveSession (String ^SessionId);
};
```

I get a warning C4538 on the first {. Does anybody has any clue why this happens and what it warns for, or is this also a compiler bug as it is for the situation in this question: [Seemingly inappropriate compilation warning with C++/CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12151060/seemingly-inappropriate-compilation-warning-with-c-cli)

Although I see they are somewhat related, I do not have a `Group` object but a `ConcurrentDictionary`. I am using Visual Studio 2010 targeting the .NET 4.0 framework and compiling with the /clr compiler flag on.

The exact error message is:

```
1>d:\t4edevnet2010\umra2\iampowershell\mcIpSessions.h(25): warning C4538: 'cli::array<Type,dimension> ^' : const/volatile qualifiers on this type are not supported
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Type=System::Collections::Concurrent::ConcurrentDictionary::Node ^,
1>              dimension=1
1>          ]
1>          This diagnostic occurred while importing type 'System::Collections::Concurrent::ConcurrentDictionary ' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
1>d:\t4edevnet2010\umra2\iampowershell\mcIpSessions.h(25): warning C4538: 'cli::array<Type,dimension> ^' : const/volatile qualifiers on this type are not supported
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Type=int,
1>              dimension=1
1>          ]
1>          This diagnostic occurred while importing type 'System::Collections::Concurrent::ConcurrentDictionary ' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
1>d:\t4edevnet2010\umra2\iampowershell\mcIpSessions.h(25): warning C4538: 'cli::array<Type,dimension> ^' : const/volatile qualifiers on this type are not supported
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Type=System::Collections::Concurrent::ConcurrentDictionary<TKey,TValue>::Node ^,
1>              dimension=1
1>          ]
1>          d:\t4edevnet2010\umra2\iampowershell\mcIpSessions.h(25) : see reference to class generic instantiation 'System::Collections::Concurrent::ConcurrentDictionary<TKey,TValue>' being compiled
1>          d:\t4edevnet2010\umra2\iampowershell\mcIpSessions.h(25) : see reference to class generic instantiation 'System::Collections::Concurrent::ConcurrentDictionary<TKey,TValue>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              TKey=System::String ^,
1>              TValue=IamPowershell::mcSession ^
1>          ]
1>          This diagnostic occurred while importing type 'System::Collections::Concurrent::ConcurrentDictionary::Node ' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
1>d:\t4edevnet2010\umra2\iampowershell\mcIpSessions.h(25): warning C4538: 'cli::array<Type,dimension> ^' : const/volatile qualifiers on this type are not supported
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Type=int,
1>              dimension=1
1>          ]
1>          This diagnostic occurred while importing type 'System::Collections::Concurrent::ConcurrentDictionary::Node ' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
1>d:\t4edevnet2010\umra2\iampowershell\mcIpSessions.h(25): warning C4538: 'cli::array<Type,dimension> ^' : const/volatile qualifiers on this type are not supported
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Type=System::Collections::Concurrent::ConcurrentDictionary<System::String ^,mcSession ^>::Node ^,
1>              dimension=1
1>          ]
1>d:\t4edevnet2010\umra2\iampowershell\mcIpSessions.h(25): warning C4538: 'cli::array<Type,dimension> ^' : const/volatile qualifiers on this type are not supported
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Type=int,
1>              dimension=1
1>          ]
1>
```

Comment: Please show us the exact error message.

Comment: I just added the complete error message in the question.

Comment: Looks like the exact same case as the one you linked, there are several members of ConcurrentDirectionary that are declared *volatile*.  Use the #pragma warning as shown.  No repro in VS2012, this bug looks to be fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @HansPassant noted in the comment on the question he is right. The members are indeed volatile (stupid me, could have checked that :S) Anyway that should be the answer.
Thankx I consider it solved now.

Answer (score 1):

As noted, the issue is the volatile members in ConcurrentDictionary. However, from the code you've shown, you don't need to inherit from ConcurrentDictionary.

In general, I believe you only need to inherit from collection classes if you're making a generic, reusable collection class. That doesn't appear to be the case here, it appears to be very specific to the `mcSession` class, and probably has business logic, not simple collection logic.

Would it work if you declared your class like this?

```
ref class mcSessions
{
private:
    static ConcurrentDictionary<String^, mcSession^>^ g_Sessions;
    TimeSpan MaxIdleTime;
    mcSessions (TimeSpan newMaxIdleTime);
public:
    static void Initialize (long MaxIdleMinutes);
    static void Shutdown ();
    static void CreateSession (String ^&SessionId);
    static void RunInSession (String ^SessionId, String ^Command);
    static void RemoveSession (String ^SessionId);
};
```

Edit: or like this?

```
ref class mcSessions
{
private:
    static mcSessions^ g_Sessions;// static session manager
    ConcurrentDictionary<String^, mcSession^>^ SessionList; // instance variable on g_Sessions
    TimeSpan MaxIdleTime;
    mcSessions (TimeSpan newMaxIdleTime);
public:
    static void Initialize (long MaxIdleMinutes);
    static void Shutdown ();
    static void CreateSession (String ^&SessionId);
    static void RunInSession (String ^SessionId, String ^Command);
    static void RemoveSession (String ^SessionId);
};
```

Comment: Well I do understand your point. But what I have here is a global session manager. So I need one instance of the mcSessions class. The static to store this instance I've put inside the mcSessions class itself (it has to be in some class somewhere and I considered this a good place). Because it is a collection of sessions it is inherited from the collection class. I more private properties (and one private function wich is run by a timed thread) In my case I consider my design correct. (Where is in your suggestion the mcSessions object stored?)

Comment: See edit. For something like this, I generally think mcSessions "has a" list of sessions, not "is a" list of sessions. "Has a" implies composition, "is a" implies inheritance.

Comment: Why should I do this? I mean `mcSessions` IS a list of sessions. Although I would have agreed with you a couple of years ago I think after doing a lot of developing it is good OO to inherit from the collection. But I guess we will keep disagreeing on this point :).